# Open un-associated files with Adobe Air

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I know it is possible to open files with their default application using the `openWithDefaultApplication` method of the file class. However, when you try to open an un-associated file (perhaps a proprietary or custom extension) using this method, a runtime error is thrown.

Is there anyway to prompt the user to open a file with a particular application like Windows does with it's "Open with..." dialog?

If not using the AIR the framework, via the NativeProcessAPI?

---

**SOLUTION** - using Pixel Elephants answer below as a foundation:

```
var processInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();                      
    processInfo.workingDirectory = file.parent;             
    processInfo.executable = new File("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe");

    var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();       
    args.push("/c");
    args.push(file.name);

    processInfo.arguments = args;

    var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();

    try
    {
        process.start(processInfo);
    }
    catch(e:Error)
    {
        //give up - open the folder
        file.parent.openWithDefaultApplication();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>The "Open with..." dialog on Windows shows whenever you try to launch an application that does not have an associate file type. Launch the application with NativeProcess.start() and Windows will take care of either opening it with the correct program, or presenting a selection screen if there is no file type associated.</s>

Alternatively, depending on what you are trying to do, you may be interested in associating file types with your AIR application. For instance, you can associate PNG files with your AIR app so that they will by default open in your AIR app (e.g. double-clicking a PNG file will launch your app with an INVOKE event specifying the PNG file that was opened). See http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=File_formats_1.html under "Declaring file type associations" for more information.

Of course, your AIR app may have no capabilities to handle opening whatever file you are trying to open and you want a different program to handle it, in which case you can just use the first method which will let the operating system take care of launching the application with the correct program.

**EDIT :**

I got confused as to what Native Process actually does. NativeProcess launches executables - NOT files, so the method above won't work.

Instead of trying to open the file directly with NativeProcess, try opening the program that you want to open the file with and pass the file in as an argument. For instance, if you want to open a PNG file with some special image program, you would do something like this:

```
var imageEditorProgram:File = new File("C:/Path/To/Program.exe");

var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
args.push("C:/Path/To/Image.png");

var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = imageEditorProgram;
nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = args;

var nativeProcess:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
nativeProcess.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
```

This should open the image editing program with the image file passed in.

However, the downside with this method is that you can't just let the operating system determine which program to open the file with. You should be able to open a file browse dialog and allow the user to select the program to open the file with (similar to how the operating system does it). So, hopefully the following would do what you want:

```
var file:File = File.userDirectory;
file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler);
file.browse();

private function selectHandler(e:Event):void{
    file.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler);
    var filePath:String= file.nativePath;
    var imageEditorProgram:File = new File(filePath);

    var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
    args.push("C:/Path/To/Image.png");

    var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
    nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = imageEditorProgram;
    nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = args;

    var nativeProcess:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
    nativeProcess.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);

}
```

I haven't tested the above code, but it should open a file browse dialog allowing the user to select a program to open the file with (perhaps you should add a FileFilter to restrict the user to selecting only .exe), and then launch that program using NativeProcess.

For user-friendliness you should consider saving user preferences for filetypes (so instead of forcing them to go through the file browser every time they want to open a PNG, just remember that they like to open PNG's with AwesomeImageEditor.exe).

Comment: The former part of your answer is what I am attempting to do - pass any file irrespective of extension (ie. it is not feasible to list them as supported types with the application) and have it prompt the user to choose an application to open the file with. Using `NativeProcessStartupInfo` assigning my file to the startupInfo and then passing that into the `start()` of a `Native Process` instance results in an error: `Error: Error #3219: The NativeProcess could not be started. '%1 is not a valid Win32 application.` The app has appropriate permissions in the update descriptor `extendedDesktop`

Comment: @James Huh, interesting. You can run the file outside of AIR, correct? The only thing I can think of is that you might have typed the path wrong and it's pointing at the wrong location or something like that? Does reading the file with a normal FileStream work?

Comment: passing the same file instance into a fileStream it works fine, just not when trying via a native process. Am I missing some arguments for the process maybe?

Comment: @James your arguments comment just triggered my brain. I was forgetting what NativeProcess actually does. I've edited my answer with the (hopefully) correct solution.

Comment: You were almost there - the right logic. Had to pass the cmd.exe as the executable and the file name as the parameter with and additional /c argument too. And then also set the working directory to the file's parent. Works for windows tried similar logic for OSX but didn't work! Thanks for the help!